# Laravel 5.5 and Angular in subdomain

Tags: angular, laravel, vagrant, subdomain

I'm working on a small project with laravel and angular and I got stuck trying to install a working app in my project subdomain. What I want to do is use Laravel 5.5 on the back-end and use angular as frontend. The thing is that I want my Laravel project to be in domain.com and my angular app in app.domain.com
I tried installing Angular in a sub-folder in my current project but when I 
`ng serve` from my subfolder the localhost is on a different port.
I want to work on this locally with vagrant. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to serve your Angular app with 'ng serve'. This is for development purposes only.

The best approach is to build the app with 'ng build' and then serve the generated folder (/dist) the way you want.

Take a look here for the [official doc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) with complete explanation about this.